# Incorrect arguments at Request.callListeners in Express/dynamodb/passport script

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

as i haven't found this error in correlation with dynamodb and passport here yet i really wanted to open this post. When i try to login with my node script this error crashes the whole Express app.

```
~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
        throw err;
        ^

           Error: Incorrect arguments
at Request.callListeners ~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:107:43)
at Request.emit ~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit ~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
at Request.transition (~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at ~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
at Request.callListeners (~/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
at Request.emit (~node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
```

this is the signup script in which i believe the query causes the error:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bCrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  //testing purposes
   "region": "us-west-2",
  "accessKeyId": "abcde",
  "secretAccessKey": "abcde",  
  "endpoint": "http://localhost:8001"
});

module.exports = function(passport) {

  passport.use("login", new LocalStrategy({
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req,username,password,done) {
      var queryParams = {
    TableName: "users",
    KeyConditionExpression: "username = :user",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      //username entered in jade form
      ":user":{"S":username}
           }
      };
      //querying dynamodb for username
      dynamodb.query(queryParams,
    function(err,user) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(username);
        console.error(err);
        return done(err);
      }
      //if no users with said username in db
      if(user.Count < 1) {
        console.error("user: " + username + " not found in db");
        return done(null, false, req.flash("message" , "user not found"));
      }
      //too many entries (admin's fault)
      if(user.Count > 1){
        console.error("error, more than one user with " + username + " in db");
        return done(null,false,req.flash("message", "more than version of the username in the db"));
      } else {
        //only one user exists in db, query for username was successful
        user.Items.forEach(function(item){

        //checking if entered password is wrong
        if(!isValidPassword(item.username, item.password)) {
        console.error("invalid username - password combination");
        return done(null,false,req.flash("message","invalid user-password combination")); 
           }


      //passwortcheck wird gar nicht ausgeführt - query returnt noch nicht die richtigen Ergebnisse
      //successful login - user and password match
      console.log("login successful");
      console.log(user.username); //undefined
      console.log(user.password); //undefined
      console.log(user);
      //return user object for serialization
      return done(null,user);
      });
     }
    });  

      //passport serialization to support persitent login sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    console.log("serializing user: " + user);
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      console.log("deserializing user: " + user);
      done(err,user);
    });
  });
  }
));


  var isValidPassword = function(user, password) {
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think endpoint is causing some problem here. You might wanna check it. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#constructor-property

Comment: Seemed to be thrown by bcrypt and not the aws-sdk. Opened an issue in their Github and they suspected it was thrown by bcrypt.